# How to use Symfony Table Helper inside phpunit?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5, phpunit

This article shows that laravel' artisan commands support `$this->table($headers, $data)` which uses "Symfony Table Helper" under the hood to display a cli table from arrays of scalars.

https://mattstauffer.com/blog/advanced-input-output-with-artisan-commands-tables-and-progress-bars-in-laravel-5.1/

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/tablehelper.html

I would like to use this functionality inside phpunit for debugging.

```php
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> new Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Table()
TypeError: Too few arguments to function Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Table::__construct(), 0 passed in Psy Shell code on line 1 and exactly 1 expected
>>> app(\Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface::class)
Illuminate/Contracts/Container/BindingResolutionException with message 'Target [Symfony/Component/Console/Output/OutputInterface] is not instantiable.'
>>> app()->make(\Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface::class)
Illuminate/Contracts/Container/BindingResolutionException with message 'Target [Symfony/Component/Console/Output/OutputInterface] is not instantiable.'
>>> app()->make(\Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Table::class)
Illuminate/Contracts/Container/BindingResolutionException with message 'Target [Symfony/Component/Console/Output/OutputInterface] is not instantiable while building [Symfony/Component/Console/Helper/Table].'
>>>
```

Right now I can't figure out how to instantiate the helper object. I would like to make a `dump_table` function that can be used in tinker and phpunit similar to the existing `dump` helper.

Answer (score 1):

I put together a solution:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Table as SymfonyTable;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput;

class Table
{
    static function dump ($headers, $rows = null) {
        if ($rows === null) {
            $rows = $headers;
            $headers = null;
        }
        if (!$rows || count($rows) === 0) {
            dump('no table data');
        }

        $output = new StreamOutput(fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
        $table = new SymfonyTable($output);

        if ($headers === true) {
            $table->setHeaders(array_keys($rows[0]));
        } else if (is_array($headers) && count($headers) > 0) {
            $table->setHeaders($headers);
        }

        $table->setRows($rows);
        // writes to output
        $table->render();
    }
}
```

It can be used like this in `php artisan tinker`:

```php
>>> App\Console\Table::dump([[1,2],[3,4]]);
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
+---+---+
>>> App\Console\Table::dump(true, [[1,2],[3,4]]);
+---+---+
| 0 | 1 |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
+---+---+
=> null
>>> App\Console\Table::dump(['a', 'b'], [[1,2],[3,4]]);
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
+---+---+
=> null
```